# Converting date from SQLite manager to real time (mountain standard time)

Tags: sqlite

I'll admit Im not the sharpest tool in the shed but I could really use some help. I need to convert this SQLite manager date 399082293 to the? I know next to nothing about SQlite so if anyone can covert it to Mountain Standard Time I would really appreciate it it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT datetime(399082293, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

the result given for me is:

> 1982-08-25 01:11:33

There is more information about various date formatting options in SQLite on [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) page.